# placement of response object on an aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, response

I've created a button that will execute a reponse.write procedure to write a string on the page, but I want to place the response at the end of the page, after all my other asp controls because write now it is placing the string from response.write at the top of the aspx page. Can anyone help me out with that?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to do a response.write to do what you want.  If you want it at the bottom of the page, but still in the markup (html) then add a [label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.aspx) to the bottom of the page and programatically change the content and visibility.  If you want it outside the markup, then override render and stick it at the end.  Check out the [page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479007.aspx#aspnet-pageobjectmodel_topic3) for a detailed explanation as to why

edit:
You can try an ASP.NET [Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.aspx) object or a [literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.aspx) (to which you can add your own markup).

Comment: thanks, but I guess the reason I'm using it is because I have to stick a html table that will be scalable based on the users response, so I wasn't sure how to write that programatically so I decided on using response.write to write it through a foreach loop. do you happen to have any idea on that?

Comment: Yes, use a label or a PlaceHolder.

Comment: Add an ASP.NET table to your page and you can manipulate it in code to your heart's content. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.aspx

Comment: Thank you man, using a label worked like a charm! I'm just curious though, how would you manipulate the ASP.NET table, like, how would you add text to rows and columns through a loop? I've been trying to figure out and it will be great if you can explain it to a asp.net newbie like me :P

Comment: Here's a little tutorial on how to how to add cells to a table: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7bewx260%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely consider using a literal control, and setting its text property.  The label control adds some HTML bloat to your final markup, especially if you are using master pages.  See [this page](http://weblogs.asp.net/chintanpshah/archive/2009/11/28/asp-label-vs-asp-literal-best-practices.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

or you can place your Response.Write directly in aspx page (at the place you like):

```
 <% Response.Write("Your text"); %>

 <% Response.Write(myMethod()); %>
```

or more simply with inline syntax:

```
 <%= Your text %>

 <%= myMethod(); %>
```

with code behind (.cs) :

```
protected string myMethod()
{
    return "Your text from code behind";
}
```